# Junit Test for method with random number

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to create a Junit test for a method which is using a simple random number for calling another simple method which returns rock, paper, or scissor depending on the value of the parameter.

I don't know how to do this.

```
public class Play {

    public String player2Choice() {

        // Create a Random object.
        Random random = new Random();

        // Ramdon number between 1-3
        int numberChoice = random.nextInt(3) + 1;

        // Return the player random choice
        return getItem(numberChoice);
    }

    public String getItem(int numberChoice) {

        String item;

        switch (numberChoice) {
        case 1:
            item = "rock";
            break;
        case 2:
            item = "scissors";
            break;
        case 3:
            item = "paper";
            break;
        default:
            item = null;
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

Right now I have this test:

```
Play play;

@Before
public void setup() {

    play = new Play();
}

@Test
public void testPlayer2Choice() {

    int param = 1;
    Play play2 = Mockito.mock(Play.class);


    play2.getItem(param);
    Mockito.verify(play2).getItem(param);

    String result = play.player2Choice();

    assertEquals("rock", result);


}
```

Comment: There is a general principle with any kind of testing.  Before you write the test, be clear in your own mind _exactly_ what requirement you are trying to test.  Don't think in terms of "test this class" or "test this method".  Think in terms of testing a requirement.  If you don't know what requirement you're testing, you'll never be able to write a good test.

Answer (score 4):

`Play` is tightly coupled to `Random`, which it really has no control over. This makes testing specific number choices difficult.

If the goal is to test that given a number choice of `1`, `player2Choice` returns `"rock"` then more control of the so-called randomness is needed.

```
public interface RandomInteger {
    int nextInt(int max);
}
```

The implementation of the interface will encapsulate an actual `Random` class and proxy the desired behavior/functionality

```
public class RandomIntegerImplementation : RandomInteger {
    private Random random ;

    public RandomIntegerImplementation() {
        // Create a Random object.
        random  = new Random();
    }

    public int nextInt(int max) {
        return random.nextInt(max);
    }
}
```

Play would then need to be refactored to explicitly depend on the now abstraction random provider.

```
public class Play {
    private RandomInteger random;

    public Play(RandomInteger random) {
        this.random = random;
    }

    public String player2Choice() {
        // Ramdon number between 1-3
        int numberChoice = random.nextInt(3) + 1;

        // Return the player random choice
        return getItem(numberChoice);
    }

    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

So now if the above stated test case is to be satisfied, the dependency can be mocked to behave as expected.

```
RandomInteger random;

Play play;

@Before
public void setup() {
    random = Mockito.mock(RandomInteger.class);
    play = new Play(random);
}

@Test
public void testPlayer2Choice_Given_Zero() {
    //Arrange
    String expected = "rock";
    int numberChoice = 0;

    when(random.nextInt(3)).thenReturn(numberChoice);

    //Act
    String actual = play.player2Choice();

    //Assert
    Mockito.verify(play).getItem(numberChoice + 1);
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

This should be enough for a start. The same can be done for other test cases.

Eventually `getItem` could also be refactored out into its own service but that is outside of the scope of the original question.